# Short lived provisioning profiles?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Does anyone else have this problem? Recently I've noticed that all my provisioning profiles are marked invalid after just a few days. Even distribution profiles that I've used to sign apps that are currently live in the app store. I'm finding myself having to create a new provisioning profile every time I submit a new build. What's causing this to happen?

[image]